# MKH 415 T POWER

Tags: mkh415-t, sennheiser, microphone, phantom

I have been offered a matching pair of Sennheiser MKH415 mics that are powered by T Power rather than 48 phantom. I record on Sound devices 702t and Fostex Fr2le and therefore cannot supply the right power without a T power converter. Do any of you still use T Powered mics on location recording. I have heard these really stand up well to the later 416 and would like some advice.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about the 415's, but we have an MKH816T at work and it works great. If you like, you can hear it compared to the other shotgun mics we have. I did a post about it on my website a few months back: http://www.dynamicinterference.com/2010/08/04/shotgun-shootout/

As for supplying T-power, you can purchase a Phantom Power to T-power converter ($60 a pop). We have one for those times when we're using our Zaxcom kit instead of Sound Devices kit. Here's one through B&H: http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/147515-REG/Sennheiser_12T_P48_12TP48_48V_Phantom.html

You'll want to get the pinout on the mics verified to make sure they're correct.If that happened, it would fry the mics. More often than not, it was cables that caused issues.  There were some instances where it was mis-wiring on the mic side but those were rare...so best to check them. That issue was one of the reasons why the industry switched to Phantom 48, that problem doesn't exist with it.

Comment: Thanks Shaun, that barrel converter is just what I was looking for as its far more compact than the large t power box.

Comment: T powering is interesting because mics can be wired balanced or Unbalanced. An easy way to interface them to Nagra recorders was to use the -10v regulated supply Nagras's used. A downside to this was as the the 10v was negative with respect to the earth/ground/0v/common connection, cables had be be wired with the + & - phase inputs the opposite way round to the DIN standard.  Good news is the MKH T powered mics seemed quite tolerant of having the power connection reversed if the wrong lead was chosen, just no sound tho.   

Answer (score 2):

I have a Sennheisser 815T and an 816T and I run them off either my Sound Devices 302 mixer or, when operating on my Sound Devices 552, I use an old Sennheiser T-power box. 
I have just ordered a barrel adapter that converts 48V Phantom to 12V Tpower from B&H Photo Video for USD 38.00 and I expect that will work nicely too and be a lot less bulky than the old T-power box!
Both mics work beautifully on T-power...they are actually my favourite mics!  :)

Comment: Thanks for the info Andre, glad they are your favoured mics I have heard a lot of other people prefer them to the newer models